# How to restrict a webapi controller method invokation using a filter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have several controllers, and each of them has operations that represents 
REST endpoints.

i want to invoke those operations based on conditions

can it be possible to achieve it using filters with attributes and not using (if..else) statements in all operations?

if so, can you please provide a skeleton of how doing it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is asp.net core then check please this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You can do something like this

```
public class SampleAsyncActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            // do something before the action executes
            var resultContext = await next();
            // do something after the action executes; resultContext.Result will be set
        }
    }
}
```